# Facebook API issue when deleting some comments

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-comments

Whenever I try to delete a comment made to a Wall post originating from FB I get the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#1705) Selected wall post for deletion does not exist.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 1705
  }
}
```

Now this doesn't make any sense since the comment has can_remove attribute set to true, and I can delete any comment made to a post by the app, only the comment to a post which was posted in FB isn't deletable. Any ideas?